# AngularJs routing issue 404

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am completely new to the AngularJS, trying to learn MVC with AngularJS, sort of mini SPA. For some reason the AngularJS routing is not working for me. I have tried so many combinations, non of them worked. Any clues what I might have wrong? The error I receive is 'The resource cannot be found' 404 when clicked on the button with a link that MVC does not have view method implemented for. It seems like MVC routing is being processed before angularJs client side routing is:

Layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-superhero.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/registration-module.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("head", false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name xxx", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content" ng-app="registrationModule">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p></footer>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Registration", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //  name: "Application",
            //  url: "{*url}",
            //  defaults: new { controller = "Registration", action = "Index" });
        }
    }
```

Angular registration:

```html
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", ['ngRoute','ngResource'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        //$routeProvider.when('/Registration/Courses', { templateUrl: '/Templates/courses.html', controller: 'CoursesController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Courses', { templateUrl: '/Templates/test.html' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Instructors', { templateUrl: '/Templates/instructors.html', controller: 'InstructorsController' });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

View

```html
@model Ang2.Models.Registration.Registration

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-brand">
                    <li><span class="navbar-brand"></span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Registration/Courses">Browse Catalog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Registration/Instructors">Browse Instructors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

Physical files exist:

[image]

Comment: My initial solution to teh above is: $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using HTML5 routing mode `html5Mode(true)`, but have not specified the base url, so that angular knows where to start the routing. You could try either disable the HTML5 mode (set it to false), or specify the base using `<base>` tag.

Note that server-side (C# code) is completely unrelated and not used for client-side routing. Also note that you should not expect your controllers to be called, because angular routing is a client-side only, it does not call the server by itself. Means, "view" will NOT be processed by c#, you will just get plain html.

All in all, it looks you don't need angular routing at all, since you seem to be doing routing server side.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need AngularJS routing, that is why I have posted the question. I need both, MVC and AngularJS. I know it is possible. Don't understand why this is not working though. What about that base tag, what do I need to do with it to make the AngularJS routing working. The registrationModule looks correct. It does not work those html templates

Comment: Angular can't do server-side routing, because it runs in the browser, and is a client-side framework. You are trying to request html view, which is supposed to be processed by C# (it uses razor engine, i.e. has elements like `@ViewBag.Title`). It does not seem to make sense. Anyways, base is used like this `<base href="/" >"`, set href to where you client-side routing should start.

Comment: I am aware of that, I dont think you understand the problem, nvm, this seem to be solution: $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false }); Thanks

Comment: BTW, you have pointed out the valid solution as well, adding the base solved the problem as well. Thanks